# If two conditions match in xpath, how do I select the one I want by giving priority

Tags: xpath

```
 <Test> 
      <input id="next_step_button" value = "Done"/> 
      <Span class = "Hogwarts">Done<span/>
 </Test>
```

Now let's assume this is my xpath:
     `(//*[@value='Done'] | //*[normalize-space(text())='Done'])`

This will return both the elements. And during execution, it will pick the first one. 
But, I want to select only specific. In this example, second one.

Comment: One way that I can handle this is to split the xpath into two and add it to ArrayList and then do a for loop on the array in such a way that if the first one is success, ignore the second one.

Answer (score 0):

This Xpath does what you want provided that elements are siblings as in your sample

- Select element if its value=Done regardless of @value=Done element position.
- Select element containing @value=Done if there's no sibling element with value=Done.

`'//*[(.="Done" and not(@value="Done")) or (@value="Done" and not(following-sibling::*[.="Done"] or preceding-sibling::*[.="Done"]))]'`